# How to sum two table counts in same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables in my postgesql db.

- Cities: id, Name
- Workers: id, city_id, name
- Suppliers: id, city_id, name

I want to create an sql query to get sum of two tables in same city like:

```
City    w_count     s_count
A       5               2
B       8               4
C       9               7
E       9               0
E       0               1
```

sql is

```
select c.name, w.total, s.total
from (select city_id, count(*) as total from workers ) w
left join (select city_id, count(*) as total from suppliers) s
on w.city_id = s.city_id,
city as c
where c.id = w.city_id and c.id = s.city_id
```

If there is no suppliers in any city and there are workers in a city, the row is missing. But the cell should be 0.

How can I do this query?

Comment: Do you really want two E rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be joining from the `city` table to the 2 count subqueries:

```sql
SELECT c.Name AS City,
       COALESCE(w.total, 0) AS w_count,
       COALESCE(s.total, 0) AS s_count
FROM city c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT city_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM workers
    GROUP BY city_id
) w
    ON w.city_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT city_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM suppliers
    GROUP BY city_id
) s
    ON s.city_id = c.id;
```

Comment: is my query optimum for this job? Or is there more performance query alternative?

Comment: There are other approaches, but the above should have decent performance for modestly sized tables.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  Does your city table report the same city more than once?

Comment: The previous comment was wrong Tim, there is no duplicated. But if there a worker in city 1 but no supplier in city 1, there is no row about it.

Comment: That can't happen if the city table is a master list of all cities.  If not, then you would have to resort to a full outer join approach, but better to fix your city table first.